# Symfony2: how to get the Type that a form is constructed from

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to dynamically generate my forms based on the user's permissions for that I have created a extension which adds listeners to forms and filters their fields accordingly.this works just fine However I'm having trouble with getting the typeName (returned from the `getName` method for classes which implement the `FormTypeInterface`) of each field (which is `FormInterface`).I've tried `FormInterface::getName` but that returns the field name that is given to the builder e.g: `$builder->add('fieldName',new FooType())` when I call `getName` on a `FormInterface` that is constructed like this I get "fieldName".What I want is the returned value from `FooType::getName`.How can I do that?I have also checked `FormInterface->getConfig->getName()` but that also gave the same same Result.the code for the listener:

```
class FooListener implements EventSubscriberInterface{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    //set low priority so it's run late
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => array('removeForbiddenFields', -50),
    );
}

public function removeForbiddenFields(FormEvent $event){

    $form = $event->getForm();

    $formName = $form->getName();/*what I want for this is to return the name of the
    type of the form.e.g: for the field that is construced with the code below 
    it must return FooType::getName*/

    $fields = $form->all();

    if($fields){
        $this->removeForbiddenFormFields($form, $formName, $fields);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
class barType extends AbstractType{   

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('fieldName',new FooType());
}
....

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those of you using Symfony 3 this can now be done with:

```
$formClass = $form->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType();
```

`$formClass` will be a stdClass representation of the class itself (not the instance of it though), and you can use `get_class($formClass)` to get a string for its FQCN, e.g. `"App\Form\Type\SillyFormType"`.

I've not tested this on Symfony 4, though it'll likely be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
$form->getConfig()->getType()->getName();
```

this will return a name returned from the `FooType::getName` through a `ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy` class.

Answer (score 1):

From Symfony > 2.8 getName() is deprecated and removed.

You can now use:

```
   $form->get('fieldName')->getConfig()->getInnerType()
```

To get specific FieldName Type.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is what you are looking for, this goes in the form `FormName`

```
public function __construct($permissions = null) {
    $this->permissions = $permissions;
}
```

and this is how you create the form, while in `buildForm` you can use an `if` or some other logic

```
$myForm = $this->createForm(new FormName($user->getPermissions()));
```